# Stored proc outbound gateway null parameter handling

Tags: spring-integration

How can i make this code work even if payload.second is null (optional parameter).

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway id="outGtw" 
                                       data-source="someDs" 
                                       request-channel="someChannel" 
                                       reply-channel="someOtherChannel" 
                                       stored-procedure-name="someStoredProcedure"
                                       ignore-column-meta-data="true">
  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="first"/>
  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="second"/>
  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="outParam" direction="OUT" type="NVARCHAR"/>
  <int-jdbc:parameter name="first" expression="payload.first"/>
  <int-jdbc:parameter name="second" expression="payload.second"/>
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Getting error when this is `null` -

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Required input parameter 'second' is missing
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreatorFactory$CallableStatementCreatorImpl.createCallableStatement(CallableStatementCreatorFactory.java:211) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1115) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1173) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:381) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:342) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:190) ~[spring-jdbc-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcExecutor.executeStoredProcedureInternal(StoredProcExecutor.java:328) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcExecutor.executeStoredProcedure(StoredProcExecutor.java:297) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(StoredProcOutboundGateway.java:60) ~[spring-integration-jdbc-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:313) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_31]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:92) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice$2.doWithRetry(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:88) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263) ~[spring-retry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:193) ~[spring-retry-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:85) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Show more StackTrace, please. Need to understand the root of cause. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the StackTrace. Looking into that I see only the single place when you can't have the parameter - `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory`:

```
public boolean hasValue(String paramName) {
        try {
            Object value = doGetValue(paramName, true);
            if (value == ERROR) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (ExpressionException e) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Could not evaluate expression", e);
            }
            if (this.cache) {
                values.put(paramName, ERROR);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The `CallMetaDataContext#matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters` can't populate the `second` parameter because that `hasValue()` returns `false`.
And this happens only in case of an `ExpressionException`.

Switch on `DEBUG` logging for the `org.springframework.integration.jdbc` category and you'll the reason.

I guess you show here just only the simple expression (`payload.second`) representation do not complicate this SO question.

Comment: Thanks Artem, i was not using ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory, but for some reason as i was making other changes the error seem to have gone away, without nay noticeable change.