# Null value in Spring Integration stored procedure parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is there a way to have Spring Integration call a stored procedure (that accepts an optional parameter) via its `stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter` such that it passes either an int parameter or a null value, if the property for the corresponding parameter is not set? I have this in my config:

```
<int-jdbc:parameter name="mykey" type="java.lang.Integer" value="${mykey:null}" />
```

But it gives me a TypeMisMatchException if `mykey` is not set because it tries to map null to an integer value (mykey would be passed to the Spring app as an optional parameter on the command line). I could go and change the default from null to 0 or so and change the stored proc to handle this, but wondering if there is a way to pass an actual null value. Do I need a different type or syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<int-jdbc:parameter name="mykey" type="java.lang.Integer" value="${mykey:#{null}}" />
```

Comment: That resolves the null issue, thanks but still get this error: `ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageExcep
tion: Required input parameter 'mykey' is missing`. I am able to call the sp without any parms just fine from outside Java/Spring.

Comment: What about using expression instead of value?

Comment: I think I'm running into the same problem as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074548/stored-proc-outbound-gateway-null-parameter-handling). I'll mark this one as anwered. Thanks!